# Using Custom Font Uploaded from Google Public Folder

Tags: html, css, fonts, blogger

I am trying to use a custom font on my website that I have uploaded in a google drive. The reason I have to take this route is, the particular site is blogger which does not allow me to upload custom font. I have read [articles](http://helplogger.blogspot.in/2014/09/upload-and-use-custom-fonts-in-blogger.html) where they had suggested to use pro version of dropbox, but at this moment I am not planning to invest in a pro account. The Code I am trying to use as follows

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: keycapsflf1-webfont;
      src: url(https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B80wMxxnziQZQ09hdVFTZWo1NFE&export=download);
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: keycapsflf1-webfont;
      src: url(https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B80wMxxnziQZQ09hdVFTZWo1NFE&export=download);
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    div {
      font-family: keycapsflf1-webfont;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div>Testing</div>

</body>

</html>
```

But, this does not work. Any idea, what might be wrong?

Comment: Hey Abhijit, did you find that my answer solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Its not working because docs.google.com is sending a No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header on the resource.

Here is the error from the console:

"Redirect at origin 'https://docs.google.com' has been blocked from loading by 
Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

I tried removing the `&export=download` param on the url `https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B80wMxxnziQZQ09hdVFTZWo1NFE&export=download`  but this didn't work either so its definitely the resource sharing policy at fault.

**edit based on Spencer Wieczorek's feedback**

After disabling same origin policy in my chrome as follows the font loaded correctly confirming that the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy is the only issue that I'm facing with loading the font: [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

See screenshot below: [image: example]

Comment: That's because it's a snippet on Stack Overflow, it may not have a cross-origin policy problem on the OP's site. Also is the last part really necessary? Have you tried disabling cross-origin to see if that is the only issue (on your computer)?

Comment: thanks spencer for the feedback - i'll look into this again today.

Comment: Hi Spencer - what are your thoughts now? thanks for your time reviewing.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to ensure that was indeed the problem. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can upload custom font to your blog via `google sites`.

1. First create a new site by using Google account at `http://sites.google.com`.
2. Then create a directory name as "`fonts`" or whatever you want to choose.
3. Upload the font and then you will get the url of the font which you upload.
4. Add the font css source url to blogger header

Eg:

```
@font-face {
      font-family: keycapsflf1-webfont;
      src: url(https://sites.google.com/site/yoursitename/fonts/fontname.ttf);
    }
```